# What timezone are message created_at fields in?

Tags: stocktwits

When getting messages from stocktwits API, there is a field called `created_at`.  What timezone is this in?

Answer (score 1):

"created_at": "2012-10-08 21:43:28 UTC",

From here http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#messages-create-docs

UTC is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: I'll expand on that a bit... UTC is like Greenwich Mean Time.  That *is* its timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a dummy message, note your timezone, then compare with the field's content ;-) ?